# Formula auto applied to right length excel

Tags: excel, vba

**Context:**

I have an excel workbook in Excel-2010. The workbook contains 3 sheets called `InputData`, `Data`, and `ReferenceTable`. This is an excel app, there is a macro that takes data from `Data` and does a bunch of stuff.

The user places the data in `InputData` in the following format.

```
|   A     |  B   |   C     |
|---------|------|---------|
|UniqueID | Name |  Amount |
```

The `ReferenceTable` has a mapping of `UniqueID` to `UniqueName`. And `Data` sheet should have the format as follows.

```
|   A     |      B     |   C     |
|---------|------------|---------|
|UniqueID | UniqueName |  Amount |
```

The columns in `Data` contain formulas

1. `UniqueID`  and `Amount` is directly copied from `InputData`.
2. `UniqueName` is looked up from `RefrenceTable` using Vlookup.

**My Question:**

I currently have to copy the formula in each cell to the number of rows that are there in `InputData`, i.e. I drag the formula down. The input data can have the variable amount of rows. Keeping formula in the max number of expected rows doesn't work because then the `Data` sheet has values like 0 in unique ID and vlook-up always looks up the empty cells in `ReferenceTable`. Can I do something so that every time I place new data in InputData section the right amount of rows contain the formula?

Comment: yes, you can use `FillDown` till the last row with data

Comment: I want it to be done automatically, and not manually. Like I put any length data in InputData and Data automatically automatically updates. FillDown feels like you would have to manually do it each time.

Answer (score 0):

Use a table for the input data. When you put a formula into a table, it automatically fills it in every row in the table.

Select one of the headings on the Input tab then select Table from the Insert ribbon.

Comment: But you would still need to define the size of the table right. Say I define it to 100 but the data in input data only contains 50 rows then won't the formulas be executed for 50 blank rows? I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: Nope, tables automatically expand as users add more rows of data, and columns with formulas automatically get filled with each new row. Same with any formatting. Try it.